# In Next.js, Is there a way to change the location of the .env file to be outside of the app's folder?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm making a project that contains a Next.js app and my .env file is located in the project's root.

How do I make Next.js look for the .env file anywhere except the app's root folder?

I already tried using the dotenv package, but unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the location of the .env file, install the 'dotenv' package and add it to your next.config.js file:

```
dotenv.config({path: '../.env'})
```

(In my case the path is `../.env` to go one folder up)

To be able to access the environment variables on the client side declare them in the next.config.js file like that:

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...

  //to be able to use the environment variables on the client side
  //==============================================================
  env: {
    EXMAPLE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE: process.env.EXMAPLE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE,
  },

  ...
}

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `next.config.js` file configure the `dotenv` package as this.

```
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '/path/to/.env') });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, unfortunately. I'm trying to find the .env file 1 folder up from the app's root (also where next.config.js resides) so I used '../.env'. That's supposed to be correct, right?

Comment: Apparently, envinroment variables can only be accessed on the server side, to access them on the client side you need to add the variable to the 'env' setting in next.config.js